# AsyncSupportListenerAdapter primefaces exception

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I am new at jsf , and i am trying to do some examples usinf primefaces and when i try to run this one ,
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/chat.jsf
i am getting an exception like this.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/primefaces] threw exception [org/atmosphere/cpr/AsyncSupportListenerAdapter] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AsyncSupportListenerAdapter
```

I think i have to have an atmosphere jar file but i am not sure. Any suggestions woulde be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one helps me to solve my problem.

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Structure-of-an-Atmosphere%27s-Application