# PrimePush not received from client but no errors

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, atmosphere, primepush

I have successfully configured my webapp with PrimePush, which builds & deploys with no errors. When I attempt to 'push' from my backing bean, I do not get any errors however my client, from what I can tell, never receives it.

My setup: virgo3.0.3/tomcat 7. PF 3.5, Atmosphere 2.0.1.
(I was previously using the versions stated in the PF 3.5 userguide, but I was getting build & deployment errors - [see my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166402/primepush-classnotfoundexception).)

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Bean.java**

```
public void eventHappened()
{
   //SOMETHING HAS HAPPENED, LET THE CLIENT KNOW!
   pushContext.push("/notification", "a message");
   log.debug("I HAVE JUST SENT A PUSH");
}
```

**Client Page**

```
<h:body>
   <h:form>
      <!--SOME UI ELEMENTS ETC -->
   <h:form>

   <p:socket channel="/notification" autoConnect="false" onMessage="handleMessage"/>

   <script type="text/javascript">  
    function handleMessage(data) {  
        alert("yay");
    }  
   </script>
<h:body>
```

Now, in my log files, I successfully see `I HAVE JUST SENT A PUSH`, though no alert is shown on the browser, and I have no errors in my logs.

Now, I am relatively new to PF, so could well be missing something fundamental, however hours of searching threads and StackOverflow has not yield any solutions for me as yet.

What I have come across though, is when I view my source code after depolyment, the rendered javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {widget_j_idt95 = new PrimeFaces.widget.Socket({url:'/myProjectContextPath/primepush/notification',autoConnect:false,transport:'websocket',fallbackTransport:'long-polling',onMessage:handleMessage});});</script>
```

Looking more closely:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Socket({url:'/myProjectContextPath/primepush/notification'
```

Since I declared my URL pattern, `<url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>` I thought a possibility was that the client was listening on a different channel than what the server was sending on. So I changed as such `<url-pattern>/myProjectContextPath/primepush/*</url-pattern>`. Again, however, this would not a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**
As I previously said, I have probably missed something fundamental. I moved the javascript into my `<h:head>`To my (somewhat) delight, I was now getting errors on my Chrome console (on page load), which I have seen on other threads:

```
Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent). push.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:1
Websocket closed, wasClean: false push.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:1
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
```

Now, having searched that error, the solution seems to be to enable 'Comet and Websockets' on Glassfish. Now, I know I said my setup was with Glassfish, however, I think we are just using its libraries - (I am quite new to Maven,OSGI, etc), we deploy the webapp using tomcat/virgo and, for some reason, we have Glassfish as a dependency.

I have searched for how to enable Comets and Websockets, but my searches do not really turn up with any explanations how to.

I wonder if anyone can explain how I can enable them or what my next steps should be?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors? You can also debug in your browser to see if data comes to the client (e.g. in Chrome F12->Network->Web Sockets->Frames and if this table (Frames) has no records then you have problem on your server side)

Comment: No I don't have any Javascript errors - and no data comes in when the request should be sent to the client! (Thanks for that debugging tip!)

Comment: Is there any reason why did you set `autoConnect="false"` ?

Comment: @Nikola no, I came across a possible solution which had autoConnect="false", but it did not have any effect, nor setting it to true.

Comment: Did you check you antivirus/firewall restrictions on HTTP ports? I had similar problem with Kaspersky. Here is page where you can test your ports - http://websocketstest.com/

Comment: @Nikola I am using my localhost at the moment, so it shouldn't be an issue. I have updated my question :)

Comment: FYI - I've also used localhost when I figured out that the Kaspersky blocks my connection...